# More universal alternative to this sed command?

Tags: shell, sed

I have a variable called `$dirs` storing directories in a dir tree:

```
root/animals/rats/mice
root/animals/cats
```

And I have another variable called `$remove` for example that holds the names of the directories I want to remove from the dirs variable:

```
rats
crabs
```

I am using a for loop to do that:

```
for d in $remove; do
 dirs=$(echo "$dirs" | sed "/\b$d\b/d") 
done
```

After that loop is done, what I should be left with is:

```
root/animals/cats
```

because the loop found rats.

I have tested this approach on 3 systems but it only works as expected on 2.

Is there a more universal approach that would work on all shells?

Comment: Do I understand this right: you have two lists, and you want to remove all entries from the first list that contain an entry from the second list?

Comment: And are these lists necessarily stored in variables, or are they previously in files?

Comment: Do you insist on having a shell script for this?  How does it not work on that third system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like

```
echo "${dirs}" | grep -Ev "rats|crabs"
```

When you can't store the exclusion list in the format with |, try to change it on the fly:"

```
echo "${dirs}" | grep -Ev $(echo "${remove}" | tr -s "\n" "|" | sed 's/|$//')
```

You can use the excludeFile technique without a temp file with

```
echo "${dirs}" | grep -vf <(echo "${remove}")
```

I am not sure which of there solutions will be best supported.